# json_encode issue

Tags: php, ajax

i have this code

```
    if($_POST){
    // response hash
    $response = array('type'=>'', 'message'=>'');

    try{
        // do some sort of data validations, very simple example below
        $required_fields = array('name');
        foreach($required_fields as $field){
            if(empty($_POST[$field])){
                throw new Exception('field is empty');
            }              
        }

        // ok, field validations are ok
        // now add to data to DB, Send Email, ect.

        // let's assume everything is ok, setup successful response
        $response['type'] = 'success';
        $response['message'] = "Done";
    }catch(Exception $e){
        $response['type'] = 'error';
        $response['message'] = $e->getMessage();
    }
    // now we are ready to turn this hash into JSON
    print json_encode($response);
    exit;
}
```

and i want to redirect to page ( ok.html ) after 'success'. how can i make it

regards

Comment: Why do you want to redirect to a HTML page when you are returning JSON? I don't understand.

Comment: My guess is you want to redirect from the client side with `window.location` after success message returned

Comment: @Pekka, because Pin Cody doesn't understand the fundamentals of how HTTP works.

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect the page:

```
window.location = 'ok.html';
```

But it is better to change the current page content using javascript.

Comment: Once you have output the json string with `print(json_encode())` you cannot continue to redirect using PHP.  PHP will already have sent its headers and will not then allow you to redirect with `header("Location: http://example.com/ok.html");`  It has to be done on the client side with javascript as suggested if the JSON has already been output.

Comment: @Pin Cody - You can send in JSON information about the page redirection.

Answer (score 1):

Redirections in PHP are generally made by using

```
header("Location: NEWLOCATION");
```

Where NEWLOCATION is the url to the new page.

This should be called before you output any information on your page, since the headers are always sent before any other content (and cannot be sent afterwards).

If you wish to use the header function even after you have outputted something else, simply save all your output in a variable, so instead of echo("output") do $myvar.="output";

And then, at the end of the file, where you will know if you want to redirect or not, do an echo($myvar);

Answer (score 0):

It does not make any sense to echo something to the browser and then re-direct as the visitor will not see the message anyway.

So you can either:

1. Not echo / print anything but store the response array in a database or a session variable and then use a php header redirect to go to `ok.html`;
2. Use javascript to set a time-out and then redirect using `window.location` after the timeout.